# Is this hyphenation use considered correct?

Tags: hyphenation

*I made a ham-and-Swiss sandwich.*

I'm wondering if this sentence might be misunderstood as referring to two sandwiches if written without the hyphens. Which form is considered correct?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, it wouldn't.  It would be clearly recognized as a compound adjective to describe sandwich.

Comment: Both forms are *correct*. It's simply a matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

As English is commonly understood, "a ham and Swiss sandwich" is clearly a single sandwich (since sandwich is singular) with two ingredients (we also understand that Swiss refers to a type of cheese).

The hyphens are not necessary and can be left out without any loss of meaning.

Comment: But they can also remain, without being considered incorrect. It's style and personal choice.